# FileStream string method for Read/Write?

Tags: c#, android, .net

I am absolute beginner and I am using VS Community 2017 C# and trying to open file on my android phone (7.0 API 24) and write and read some text in that file. This is my methods that suppose to do that:

```
public string WriteFile(string fileName, byte content)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@fileName,
                               FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                               FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                               FileShare.None);
    fileStream.WriteByte(content);
    fileStream.Close();
    return "WriteOpen";
}

public string ReadFile(string fileName)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@fileName,
                   FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                   FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                   FileShare.None);
    int tekts = fileStream.ReadByte();
    fileStream.Close();
    return "" + tekts;
}
```

but I cannot find `FileStream` method with string arguments, so I use `WriteByte` and `ReadByte` just to test writing and reading file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you wrap your streams in `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`? `using(var fs = new FileStream(...)) using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs)) { sw.WriteLine(...);}`  (PS always dispose your streams / use in a `using` block)

Comment: That works fine. Thank You.